# How do I get the latest updated revision via SVN?

Tags: svn, shell

Just a quick question I haven't found an answer for by searching...

How do I get the current **checked out** revision number from my SVN-dir?

More clearly: I don't want the latest revision number since that can be my own commit, but the revision number of the latest update I made in my local repo.

Or, if that is easier, I want to be able to retrieve a list of all files that have been committed to the repo since my last update, preferably without the files I have committed myself since then.

Cheers.

Comment: All current answers tells me the latest version I have locally, but **not** the latest update I made. Because if my last commit was 1234 I'll get 1234. However if the latest revision I checked out is 1233 that is the number I want to find. (Even though I should always update to the latest revision before committing myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

svnversion displays a range of numbers

```
> svnversion
2:3
```

The first number is the last updated / checked-out version. The second number is the last checked-in version. If they are the same, you'll only see one number.

edit: be aware that if you are doing complicated checkin/checkout/merges, different parts of your working copy may be at different revisions, and svnversion will tell you the range of revision numbers. see the [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to know :)

Comment: thanks for asking -- I figured it out by messing around, wasn't aware of this feature until I tried it.

Comment: Statement about *last checked-out/checked-in version* is **wrong**. Not in general case. You can just **svn up -r $OLDREV; svn up $FILE** to get mixed copy and  you don't checked-in **$FILE** ))

Answer (score 3):

Use the [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) command.

```
$ svnversion
1234
```

would mean that 1234 is the highest revision your working copy was updated to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `svnversion` program.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn info <your local WC>
```

Any additional info:

```
C:\>svn help info
info: Display information about a local or remote item.
usage: info [TARGET[@REV]...]

  Print information about each TARGET (default: '.')
  TARGET may be either a working-copy path or URL.  If specified, REV
  determines in which revision the target is first looked up.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
  -R [--recursive]         : descend recursively, same as --depth=infinity
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                            'immediates', or 'infinity')
  --targets ARG            : pass contents of file ARG as additional args
  --incremental            : give output suitable for concatenation
  --xml                    : output in XML
  --changelist ARG         : operate only on members of changelist ARG
                             [aliases: --cl]

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
```

To the **second part** of your question:
You can use `svn diff -r BASE:HEAD`. `BASE` describes your current revision, `HEAD` the latest in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what's changed in the repo that's not in your working copy you're looking for the -u switch to the svn status command:

```
svn status -u
```

It will show you what would happen if you did an `svn up`, but without actually performing the update.

Comment: No -- the OP is looking for the version number of the last updated version. svn status -u compares against the last checked-in version which may be greater than the last updated version.

Comment: Ugh. That's what happens when I switch to decaf!

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this documentation [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html)

I think you need to use svnversion command with -c option.

--committed (-c)
Uses the last-changed revisions rather than the current (i.e., highest locally available) revisions.

Hope this help!